# Multiple int arrays pointing to same memory address?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a bug in my Arduino code that doesn't seem to make sense to me.  As a whole, this code will play musical tunes by storing information about the Frequency and Duration of notes to be played to a piezo (a single tone speaker).  In order to save memory, I declared/initialized two separate arrays (as part of a class called TuneManager) that will hold the next set of frequencies/durations, with two indexes: currentNoteIndex (which keeps track of which what note will be played next) and loadableNoteIndex (which keeps track of the next location in the arrays that can be overwritten with new note information).

```
int currentNoteIndex = 0;
int loadableNoteIndex = 0;
int tuneFreq[MAX_NOTE_BUFFER];
int tuneDur[MAX_NOTE_BUFFER];
```

Then, when it comes time to load more notes in to these arrays, I decrypt them from a string that represents the song and load them like this:

```
tuneFreq[loadableNoteIndex] = atoi(noteFreq);
tuneDur[loadableNoteIndex] = atoi(noteDur);
```

If I print out both of the noteFreq and noteDur variables, I get the expected values.  Unfortunately, if I out the saved array values I get incorrect output.

```
Serial.print(tuneFreq[loadableNoteIndex]);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(tuneDur[loadableNoteIndex]);
```

For example, if noteFreq was 150, but noteDur was 200, the output would be "200 200" instead of the expected "150 200".  Also, if I were to switch the order of the assignment statements before printing, it would print "150 150" instead of "200 150".  This leads me to believe that both arrays are somehow referencing the same memory addresses, but I can't find out what went wrong.

If you want the full code, have a look at the TuneManager cpp and h files here: https://github.com/bajuwa/RoboKitty/tree/TuneBuffer/EightBitTunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are incorrectly declared in the header:

```
private:
  int tuneFreq[];
  int tuneDur[];
```

This declares two zero sized arrays (even if you allocate arrays in the source file, it doesn't matter), which is illegal (some compiler , such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html), allows them)

You must declare the size in the header, to let the compiler know the size of your type:

```
private:
  const int MAX_NOTE_BUFFER = 25;
  int tuneFreq[MAX_NOTE_BUFFER];
  int tuneDur[MAX_NOTE_BUFFER];
```

Your program currently has undefined behavior (your are writing past the end of the "arrays"), so whatever you observe (you are in effect writing to some memory past your object) can be considered coincidental.

The fact that you write two times at that same location (a zero-sized array has a size of ... zero) explains why it looks like "both arrays have the same address", but with undefined behavior, anything else could happen.

Comment: That's not zero-sized, it's [illegal](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aedd892f0c459c2).

Comment: Thanks!  This did a wonderful job of curing my headache x)  I was so focused on the coincidence of it all that I didn't even think of the header file x.x

Comment: Allowed with gcc : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html , but Ill edit.